# Change theorem numbering from Roman to Arabic

Tags: numbering, theorems, roman-numerals

I am trying to number my theorems according to section number. I use the following in the preamble, which works:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

However, since my section is numbered as roman numeral, my theorem numbering ends up being like

> Theorem IV.1

Which is really ugly. I would like to keep my section numbering as Roman numerals but my theorem numbering as Arabic. I've tried stuff like

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\arabic{section}]
```

But this wouldn't compile. I've also looked around online but couldn't find the answer.

Pleas let me know if you know a solution to this problem. Thank you!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
```

Comment: Wow that worked! Thanks so much I looked around for so long!