# Numbering theorems differently from the section's style

Tags: numbering, theorems

I set the section numbering style to \Roman but now my theorems are numbered like so:

**Theorem IV.2.** instead of **Theorem 4.2.**

Is there a way of getting the latter but preserving the section numbering in Roman?

I've tried this [Change theorem numbering from Roman to Arabic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107775/change-theorem-numbering-from-roman-to-arabic)

```
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
```

I get

```
LaTex Error: \thetheorem command undefined.
```

Apparently this may work on other classes than article (in which I am)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show in code what you have done not words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to redefine `\thetheorem` before it's been defined. Move your `\renewcommand` after the `\newtheorem` command.

Also, the numbering for your theorems will follow the naming of the environments you've created so you should do, e.g.,

```
\renewcommand\theteo{\arabic{section}.\arabic{teo}}
```

and similarly for `lemma`.

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly